# rEFInd is not working in macos high sierra 10.13.6 on 2018 MacBook Pro 13 inch even after proper installation

Tags: high-sierra, startup, efi

I have installed rEFInd in my mac by going into recovery mode -> open terminal -> `csrutil disable` -> `cd "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/username/Downloads/refind-bin-0.11.2"` -> `bash ./refind-install` -> `csrutil enable` -> `reboot`
But on reboot it shows and loads the Apple icon first and then opens the **Boot Recovery** where I need to select my hard disk and restart the mac and it boots into macos without showing rEFInd option at the beginning. How to resolve this?

Comment: Can you confirm the file were copied to `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/refind` folder?. To do this you will need to mount the EFI partition. This can be done with the command `sudo diskutil mount disk0s1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** You'll have to run the `./refind-install` program in *macOS* after you've run `csrutil disable` in the *Recovery OS*. This will most likely solve any issues you have with installation.

**Original answer:** I think your problem is that you've tried to disable `csrutil` through a terminal in *MacOS*, which won't work. Try following the steps in [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/) to go into *Recovery OS*, run `csrutil disable; reboot` in the Terminal, and then try going through the normal *refind* install steps. It's your choice if you want to re-enable System Integrity Protection afterwards, but again you'll have to do it through *Recovery OS*.

Hopefully this advice was interesting and useful to you, and I wish you good luck.

Comment: I've already done the same thing as whatever you have answered here. I was into Recovery OS. Didn't work.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for the clarification. I've edited my answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: This answer did not work. Tried Mojave and refind v0.11.4.